# stdout file descriptor not set correctly

Tags: stdout, file-descriptor

I am calling the IBM API, QzshSystem.
Its prerequisite is to ensure the File Descriptors- 0, 1 and 2 are available in process.
My code looks like this,

```
  int fd0 = -1, fd1 = -1, fd2 = -1;

  if (fcntl(0, F_GETFL) == -1)
  {
     fd0 = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
     if (fd0 == -1) 
     {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error %d opening file /dev/null\n", errno);
     }
  }
  if (fcntl(1, F_GETFL) == -1)
  {
     fd1 = open("/apifile.out", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
     if (fd1 == -1)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d opening file %s\n", errno, "/apifile.out");
     }
  }
  if (fcntl(2, F_GETFL) == -1)
  {
     fd2 = open("/apifile.err", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
     if (fd2 == -1)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d opening file %s\n", errno, "/apifile.err");
     }
  }
```

Which is then followed with calling the API after some formatting of the arguments passed,

```
  aReturn = QzshSystem(CmdStrng);
```

The API does not work (It should run a shell cmd), and returns the error 8; which from its documentation states that stdout file descriptor, 1, is not set correctly.

How is this possible? And am I supposed to fix the file descriptor for stdout using close() and an open?